# How to Run http-server command on Jenkins Job

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, google-cloud-platform

I want to run the command http-server command on jenkins. It is a command which runs continusly it will never gets disconnected until we do the CTRL+C. What happens is the job is failed since the commmand never completes. Any solution. I want the server to run and jenkins job to be succeeded any solution??

**UPDATE:**
I made a script using os library in python and configured the commands over there and run that script this worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Jenkins ProcessTreeKiller

Any process resulting from a command executed within a Jenkins Job or Pipeline will be a child process of the respective Jenkins build node.  Jenkins, by design, kills all child processes spawned by a build once the build completes.

This feature is called [ProcessTreeKiller](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller). For Freestyle Jobs the Jenkins documentation has traditionally recommended setting the following environment variable in an Execute Shell step of your job.

```
export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe
```

A similar environment variable is required for Pipeline projects.

```
export JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe
```

If you want to globally disable this feature you can use the following Java system property

```
java -Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true -jar jenkins.war
```

More recently, the Jenkins Project documentation recommends using a daemon wrapper in conjunction with the appropriate environment variable.

```
daemonize -E BUILD_ID=dontKillMe http-server
```

If none of the aforementioned options is suitable for your particular use case you could develop your Jenkins project to publish a message to a message queue. You could then have a consumer running as a service that consumes your message and executes a command based on the message instructions.

#### Post Script

A concern was raised in the comments about modifying the BUILD_ID environment variable in a Freestyle Job.

While this is undocumented and likely deprecated, I believe you *may* use the following environment variable to prevent the ProcessTreeKiller from killing your Freestyle Job’s child processes.

```
export JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE=dontKillMe
```

Comment: That's interesting, but what if the build-script depends on `BUILD_ID`? Having a HTTP server permanently running still seems to be the most reliable approach, because the issue at hand would be become a non-issue.

Comment: Where should i add this line the executive shell in job?

Comment: @MartinZeitler Jenkins will terminate any process spawned during the execution of the build upon completion of the build. Running in background, running with nohup, etc will not work. Other than implementing a message queue or some type of sync service that executes your shell commands this is the only way to do it. You can get your build ID from a dozen different places ( underline SDK, API call to your job, etc ). You could also just save the build ID in a variable before setting the envar.

Comment: @MartinZeitler but in general I don’t disagree with you. I personally do not use this method, but it is my opinion that if you are using a Jenkins job to start a service you should implement the appropriate queues

Comment: @RamKumarK yes you add to execute shell script step in your job.  If my answer works for you please upvote and accept

Answer (score 0):

How about you execute the command as a background process?

```
http-server > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: It's actually better to pipe stdout to logfile; detaching the console with `&` is the important part.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, but use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> - or use `&` to detach the console (second option is better for scripting).
On Jenkins you might also want to obtain the PID of that process, in order to kill it again; else you'll spawn a new process with every single build. Setting up Apache or Ngnix might provide a more reliable experience; else you'll have to mess around with PID, instead of just deploying (the script will ultimately not run on `http-server` anyway).

Comment: I tried adding & at the end but the end the server is not running