# Jenkins freezes as the npm command does not return to terminal

Tags: jenkins, npm, terminal, background, nohup

Jenkins remote execute shell for Linux has the below command:

```
npm run develop
```

However, this command does not return to the terminal as below:

```
+ npm run develop

> sggs-api@0.1.0 develop
> strapi develop


 Project information

[90m┌────────────────────[39m[90m┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────┐[39m
[90m│[39m Time               [90m│[39m Tue Oct 04 2022 10:02:58 GMT+0000 (Coordinated … [90m│[39m
[90m│[39m Launched in        [90m│[39m 1201 ms                                          [90m│[39m
[90m│[39m Environment        [90m│[39m development                                      [90m│[39m
[90m│[39m Process PID        [90m│[39m 422222                                           [90m│[39m
[90m│[39m Version            [90m│[39m 4.2.3 (node v16.17.0)                            [90m│[39m
[90m│[39m Edition            [90m│[39m Community                                        [90m│[39m
[90m└────────────────────[39m[90m┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────┘[39m

 Actions available

Welcome back!
To manage your project , go to the administration panel at:
http://localhost:1337/admin

To access the server ⚡️, go to:
http://localhost:1337
```

I can put it in background like below:

```
nohup npm run develop &
```

However, I need help determining if `nohup npm run develop &` command was successful or not.

```
nohup npm run develop > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

This command also does not work.

Upon suggestion I tried the below:

```
#echo "nohup npm run develop &"
#nohup npm run develop &
#npm run develop  > /dev/null 2>&1 &
#BUILD_ID=dontKillMe nohup npm run develop &
export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe
export JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE=dontKillMe
nohup npm run develop &
```

I tried unsuccessfully those that are commented with `#` as well

The process starts and then dies away after sometime.

Below is the output:

```
+ pwd
/etc/jenkins_tmp/workspace/SGGS_QA_API
+ export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe
+ BUILD_ID=dontKillMe
+ export JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE=dontKillMe
+ JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE=dontKillMe
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo 'npm run develop was successful. Copying ...'
npm run develop was successful. Copying ...
+ nohup npm run develop

> sggs-api@0.1.0 develop
> strapi develop


 Project information

[90m┌────────────────────[39m[90m┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────┐[39m
[90m│[39m Time               [90m│[39m Tue Oct 04 2022 12:17:19 GMT+0000 (Coordinated … [90m│[39m
[90m│[39m Launched in        [90m│[39m 808 ms                                           [90m│[39m
[90m│[39m Environment        [90m│[39m development                                      [90m│[39m
[90m│[39m Process PID        [90m│[39m 424441                                           [90m│[39m
[90m│[39m Version            [90m│[39m 4.2.3 (node v16.17.0)                            [90m│[39m
[90m│[39m Edition            [90m│[39m Community                                        [90m│[39m
[90m└────────────────────[39m[90m┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────┘[39m

 Actions available

Welcome back!
To manage your project , go to the administration panel at:
http://localhost:1337/admin

To access the server ⚡️, go to:
http://localhost:1337

[2022-10-04 12:17:23.707] [32mhttp[39m: POST /admin/login (110 ms) 200
[2022-10-04 12:17:23.895] [32mhttp[39m: GET /admin/7814.ec45b22f.chunk.js (7 ms) 200
[2022-10-04 12:17:24.101] [32mhttp[39m: GET /admin/1362.b73aabfc.chunk.js (1 ms) 200
[2022-10-04 12:17:24.109] [32mhttp[39m: GET /admin/Admin-authenticatedApp.7216e34f.chunk.js (1 ms) 200
[2022-10-04 12:17:25.520] [32mhttp[39m: GET /admin/information (27 ms) 200
[2022-10-04 12:17:25.539] [32mhttp[39m: GET /admin/users/me (39 ms) 200
[2022-10-04 12:17:25.544] [32mhttp[39m: GET /admin/users/me/permissions (46 ms) 200
[2022-10-04 12:17:25.713] [32mhttp[39m: GET /i18n/locales (14 ms) 200
[2022-10-04 12:17:25.920] [32mhttp[39m: GET /admin/Admin_homePage.254acc19.chunk.js (1 ms) 200
[2022-10-04 12:17:26.144] [32mhttp[39m: GET /content-manager/components (13 ms) 200
[2022-10-04 12:17:26.159] [32mhttp[39m: GET /content-manager/content-types (25 ms) 200
Process leaked file descriptors. See https://www.jenkins.io/redirect/troubleshooting/process-leaked-file-descriptors for more information
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Can you please suggest?

Comment: Do you expect this server to stay running when the job finishes?  You should read my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73373448/how-to-run-http-server-command-on-jenkins-job/73373857#73373857

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli Do you expect this server to stay running when the job finishes? -> Yes

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli i tried `npm run develop   > /dev/null 2>&1 &` it works from server terminal but not through Jenkins

Comment: did you read my answer I linked you to?  You should run it with a service daemon and additionally you need to set some env variables. The post I gave you answers your question

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli yet it does not work. Updated the original post if you can have a look?

Comment: i'm using a jenkins DSL git project

Comment: I even restarted my jenkins with this option -> `java -Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true -jar jenkins.war` but the npm process dies after a minute or two of starting ....

Comment: You have two issues. The first issue is that the process runs in foreground. Your second issue is that when you background the process it is killed when the build finishes. Which issue are you on right now?

Comment: I need the process to be running in the background and does not get killed. I have updated the original post with all the option  tried to make it run in the background as well as your recommendations @ChrisMaggiulli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that worked in jenkins for `npm run develop` was `nohup npm run develop  >> /var/www/logs/strapi.log 2>&1 &`